# How do I manipulate a lowlevelarray in Opa?

Tags: opa

For instance, how do I create a LowLevelArray that contains a set of integers: 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5?

My understanding is that the easy way is to do myarray = @llarray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and that's great. But how do I loop through the array to pull out values and println them?

I tried do inrange(0,4,(i -> println("{myarray.get(i)}"))) but get the error: Record expression has type llarray(int) but field access expected it to have
type { get: 'a; 'r.a }

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](http://doc.opalang.org/api/index.html#llarray.opa.html). Instead of `myarray.get(i)` you'll have to write `LowLevelArray.get(myarray, i)` (you can make an abbreviation for the `LowLevelArray` module, or even the getter for a particular array, if that's too verbose for you).